# Выделить произвольную область кода. IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Как выделить какую-то произвольную область кода в IDE IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5?

К примеру, в Visual Studio это делается через

> Shift + Alt + (↑ ↓ → ←)

Собственно, как это можно сделать, если это вообще возможно, в IntelliJ?

Без этого выделения слегка неудобно редактировать. Особенно, если нужно выделить какой-то "квадратный" фрагмент кода в коде и его удалить/закомментировать. Ведь вместо горячих клавиш приходиться использовать мышь, что само по себе не очень. Я только недавно начал работать с IntelliJ.

Comment: Shift + стрелки?

Comment: https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alt + левый клик.
Можно выделять прямоугольником несколько строк.